# Extremely slow query in PostgreSQL (order by multi col)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

Please let me know if you need the table definitions. As I'm sure is obvious, I have several tables holding information about a user (`partydevicestatus`, `groupgps`) each have a foreign key relationship to the user held in `partyrelationship` and each row has an identifier of the "group" that user's in.

With this query, I simply want to, for a particular group (in this example, 6) get the user details, position and device info for each user.

I can clearly see with the explain that the Sort is the issue here, due to having 2 columns with a lot of data. However I have an index on both the columns being sorted on and it has yielded no improvement. I'm almost certain this is a terribly optimised query but I am not experienced enough with PostgreSQL to find a better one?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON("public".groupgps.groupmember)
 "public".groupgps.groupgps,
 "public".groupgps.groupmember,
 "public".groupgps.messagetype,
 "public".groupgps.lat,
 "public".groupgps.lon,
 "public".groupgps.date_stamp,
 "public".partyrelationship.to_party,
 "public".partyrelationship.to_name,
 "public".partyrelationship.image_url,
 "public".partyrelationship.partyrelationship,
 "public".partydevicestatus.connection_type,
 "public".partydevicestatus.battery_level,
 "public".partydevicestatus.charging_state,
 "public".partydevicestatus.timestamp
 FROM "public".groupgps
 INNER JOIN "public".partyrelationship
 ON "public".partyrelationship.partyrelationship = "public".groupgps.groupmember
 INNER JOIN "public".partysettings
 ON "public".partysettings.groupmember = "public".groupgps.groupmember
 LEFT JOIN "public".partydevicestatus
 ON "public".partydevicestatus.groupmember_id = "public".groupgps.groupmember
 WHERE "public".partyrelationship.from_party = 6
 AND "public".partysettings.gps_tracking_enabled = true
 ORDER BY "public".groupgps.groupmember, "public".groupgps.date_stamp DESC
```

Explain Result

```
Unique  (cost=1368961.43..1390701.85 rows=25 width=192) (actual time=24622.609..27043.061 rows=4 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=1368961.43..1379831.64 rows=4348083 width=192) (actual time=24622.601..26604.659 rows=2221853 loops=1)
        Sort Key: groupgps.groupmember, groupgps.date_stamp DESC
        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 431400kB
        ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=50.64..87013.93 rows=4348083 width=192) (actual time=0.499..3011.806 rows=2221853 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (groupgps.groupmember = partydevicestatus.groupmember_id)
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=31.66..29732.32 rows=77101 width=167) (actual time=0.153..2242.950 rows=109041 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: (groupgps.groupmember = partyrelationship.partyrelationship)
                    ->  Seq Scan on groupgps  (cost=0.00..24372.00 rows=1217200 width=50) (actual time=0.005..1933.528 rows=1217025 loops=1)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=31.48..31.48 rows=14 width=125) (actual time=0.141..0.141 rows=5 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=10.31..31.48 rows=14 width=125) (actual time=0.092..0.138 rows=5 loops=1)
                                Hash Cond: (partysettings.groupmember = partyrelationship.partyrelationship)
                                ->  Seq Scan on partysettings  (cost=0.00..20.75 rows=75 width=8) (actual time=0.003..0.038 rows=75 loops=1)
                                      Filter: gps_tracking_enabled
                                ->  Hash  (cost=9.79..9.79 rows=42 width=117) (actual time=0.076..0.076 rows=42 loops=1)
                                      Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 11kB
                                      ->  Seq Scan on partyrelationship  (cost=0.00..9.79 rows=42 width=117) (actual time=0.007..0.058 rows=42 loops=1)
                                            Filter: (from_party = 6)
                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 181
              ->  Hash  (cost=12.88..12.88 rows=488 width=29) (actual time=0.341..0.341 rows=489 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 41kB
                    ->  Seq Scan on partydevicestatus  (cost=0.00..12.88 rows=488 width=29) (actual time=0.023..0.163 rows=489 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.878 ms
Execution time: 27218.016 ms
```

Comment: "*Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 431400kB*" is your problem. Increase `work_mem` until this goes away

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Isn't that just indicative of a bad query? Sorry if i misunderstand!

Comment: You are trying to sort over 2 million rows. With the default configuration it's unlikely to fit into work_mem.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name out of interest, why is it 2 million rows? My largest table has 100,000 records!

Comment: Your join returns two million rows: `rows=2221853 loops=1`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name OK that's interesting then, perhaps i'm looking in the wrong place then? As in total across all tables i only have something like 100,500 rows of data. Where are all these additional rows coming from? I presume the join is matching multiple rows?

Comment: It's the join `groupgps.groupmember = partydevicestatus.groupmember_id` that returns that many rows

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name 400 rows total in that table, but i see you're right. I can just now see that it's even worse than i thought aha.

Comment: (When asking questions, there is no need to offer to fix it up, or that you'll add other information upon request - people will ask if they need things. Be succinct, but be detailed as well, on the first edit. For what it is worth it looks good to me - most people forget the explain plan!).

Comment: @halfer : the table definitions are missing from the question. The query plan suggests that the tables have no keys, nor indexes. And (as pointed out by a horse...) the join on groupmember is probably a logic error (it should be a PK (or CK) in at least one of the two tables)